# Graph of $y=4\sin\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

> What is the graph of the equation $$y=4\sin\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$$ along with its period and amplitude?

I got confused when the equation got cosine and sine in it. I only know how to handle graphs of an equation when only there is either cosine or sine, not altogether with sine and cosine in one equation.

Comment: Hint:$\sin 2A=2\sin A \cos A$.

Comment: $y=4 \sin(x/3) \cos(x/3) = 2 \sin(2x/3)$ So the amplitude is $2$ and the period id $3\pi$ ... now check it ...
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kcoysbbfip

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following [double-angle formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) makes graphing your curve a lot easier:
$$\sin(2\theta)\equiv 2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$$
Hence, the equation of your curve is equivalent to:
$$y=4\sin\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=2\cdot \color{green}{2\sin\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)}=2\color{green}{\sin\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)}$$
Given a [sinusoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) $y=A\sin(\omega x+\varphi)$, the amplitude is $A$ and the period is $\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega}$.